# Window minimizes when mouse leaves the window area

Tags: window, minimize

When I hover away from a window in Ubuntu, that window minimizes instantly. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Please make the question more clear.

Comment: Please indicate which version and flavor of Ubuntu you are using and how to replicate this problem. [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1195768/edit) your question and add the new details.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Do you have *focus follows mouse* enabled?

Comment: @JusticeforMonica thank you very much, i had to disable it